# Hide/Show Leaflet Routing Machine when click on button (Easy Button plugin)

Tags: leaflet, routing

I tried to put this code :

```
var rlayer = null;

L.easyButton('fa-level-up',
    function () {
        if (rlayer) {
            map.removeLayer(rlayer);
            rlayer = null;
        } else {
            var routing = L.Routing.control(...);
            rlayer = L.layerGroup([routing]);
            map.addLayer(rlayer);
        }
    }, 'Display Route').addTo(map);
```

on my map but when I click on the button, the console tells me 2 errors :

- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`
- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined`

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and edit your question to let us know what you have already tried, if the error gives more detail (line number, etc).